# Common Ports with Adium

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, adium

I was wondering if there was a way to use common ports with Adium in order to bypass firewall settings? Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Under which definition of "common ports"? Also, incoming or outgoing connections?

Comment: Im looking at ports 20, 80 and 443